# Apply colored overlay over a colored rgb image with some transparency in Skimage

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

So basically I have a colored RGB image and I want to add a colored overlay over the RGB image without converting it to gray level. 
For example if I have a colored image(RGB). And I want to add a transparent blue color over the index like this

```
img[200:350, 200:350] = [0, 0, 1] # Blue block
```

This question is a sibling question to this one:
[Applying a coloured overlay to an image in either PIL or Imagemagik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193603/applying-a-coloured-overlay-to-an-image-in-either-pil-or-imagemagik)
Difference is the color space. The above question is for gray level images rather colored (RGB).

```
from skimage import io, data
import numpy as np
img = data.astronaut()
```

Please use the above code to answer.

Comment: select the region you want to add the overlay first. Then add the color to that region

Comment: @JeruLuke the problem with that is the color is not transparent. I need to see the background too. So there should be a proper alpha channel in the overlay.

Comment: I  have the exact solution in OpenCV. Would you like to see it??

Comment: @JeruLuke, Yes Sure!!!!!!

Comment: have a look at the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code in OpenCV:

```
import cv2

# load the image
image = cv2.imread("2.jpg")

# I resized the images because they were to big
image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.75, fy=0.75)

overlay = image.copy()
output = image.copy()

#select the region that has to be overlaid
cv2.rectangle(overlay, (420, 205), (595, 385),(0, 255, 255), -1)

#Adding the transparency parameter
alpha = 1

#Performing image overlay
cv2.addWeighted(overlay, alpha, output, 1 - alpha,0, output)

#Save the overlaid image
cv2.imwrite('Output'+str(alpha) +'.jpg', output)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Some results:**

***when alpha = 0.1***

[image]

***when alpha = 0.5***

[image]

***when alpha = 0.8***

[image]

***when alpha = 1.0*** (the overlay is no longer transparent but opaque)

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks :)